# Google Maps; I use an API key,but it works like i had not put on it

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use waypoints with the directions service and i am be able to create 8 waypoints not 23. I ve done this steps:

1- I enable Google Maps Directions API  and Google Maps JavaScript API.

2- I create a browser key and a Server key. In browser key put localhost on domain.

3- I put this script on my htm:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
```

4- I use Server or Browser key and when i try to use more than 8 waypoints it appears the WAYPOINTS LIMITS MESSAGE. But

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, according to the documentation:

> The maximum number of waypoints allowed when using the Directions service in the Google Maps JavaScript API is 8, plus the origin and destination.
>
> Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination.
>
> The limits are different for the Google Maps Directions API web service.
>   Waypoints are not supported for transit directions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints

So you can use 23 waypoints in JavaScript API directions service only with the Premium plan at the moment.

Comment: Thanks very much @xomena. I send that information to my work mates. Im spanish and this link in spanish does not especify as in english page.